# Interop version in mac

Tags: java, c#, macos, outlook

Good day, i created a program using c# which converts outlook email into pdf. im already finished with the program.

and here is my code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
MAPIFolder rootFolder = outlookNs.Stores[parameters[0].ToString()].GetRootFolder();

List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();
Folders subFolders = rootFolder.Folders;
foreach (Folder folder in subFolders)
{
    Items items = folder.Items;
    foreach (object item in items)
       {
        if (item is MailItem)
          {
          }
       }


}
```

but my input is .pst file, what i received is .olm file. its outlook for mac. there are lots of olm to pst converter but i can't pay for it (i'm working for a company)

so my question is, is there a interop version for mac. so i can change my code to java?

i already did a search and i can't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no interops for MAC OS. The COM automation technology is for Windows only.

You need to use [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) if you want to automate something on MAC OS.

Answer (score 0):

To convert OLM to PST you can use a third-party library.

I prefer to use [Aspose.Email](https://products.aspose.com/email/net) for this propose. Look at an example.

```
string dst = "SampleOLM.olm";

//Initialize Olm storage
using (OlmStorage storage = new OlmStorage(dst))
{
    //Initialize Pst storage
    using (PersonalStorage pst = PersonalStorage.Create("output.pst", FileFormatVersion.Unicode))
    {
        //Create only Inbox folder as an example
        FolderInfo pstFolder = pst.CreatePredefinedFolder("Inbox", StandardIpmFolder.Inbox);

        //Go through folders in the OLM storage
        foreach (OlmFolder folder in storage.FolderHierarchy)
        {
            //Check is this folder empty
            if (folder.HasMessages)
            {
                 // extract messages from folder
                 foreach (MapiMessage msg in storage.EnumerateMessages(folder))
                 {
                     //Add message to the pst storage
                     pstFolder.AddMessage(msg);
                     Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + msg.Subject);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It`s easy to use. Also, this library has a big amount of functionality, which can improve processing emails, calendars and etc.

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.